# How do add running quarterly and yearly average columns to an existing table on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, average, calculated-columns

I have a table that looks like this (as an example):

```
+------------+----------+---------+---------+------+
|    Date    |   NAV    |  YrMn   |  YrQt   |  Yr  |
+------------+----------+---------+---------+------+
| 2/2/2015   | 20201975 | 2015-02 | 2015-Q1 | 2015 |
| 2/5/2015   | 20238246 | 2015-02 | 2015-Q1 | 2015 |
| 2/6/2015   | 20220397 | 2015-02 | 2015-Q1 | 2015 |
| 3/2/2015   | 25597902 | 2015-03 | 2015-Q1 | 2015 |
| 3/3/2015   | 25218728 | 2015-03 | 2015-Q1 | 2015 |
| 3/5/2015   | 25332618 | 2015-03 | 2015-Q1 | 2015 |
| 4/7/2015   | 25418590 | 2015-04 | 2015-Q2 | 2015 |
| 4/8/2015   | 25641822 | 2015-04 | 2015-Q2 | 2015 |
| 4/9/2015   | 25554811 | 2015-04 | 2015-Q2 | 2015 |
| 5/7/2015   | 30366075 | 2015-05 | 2015-Q2 | 2015 |
| 5/11/2015  | 30682382 | 2015-05 | 2015-Q2 | 2015 |
| 5/12/2015  | 30302426 | 2015-05 | 2015-Q2 | 2015 |
| 8/23/2016  | 33089750 | 2016-08 | 2016-Q3 | 2016 |
| 8/24/2016  | 32927879 | 2016-08 | 2016-Q3 | 2016 |
| 8/29/2016  | 32788338 | 2016-08 | 2016-Q3 | 2016 |
| 9/23/2016  | 32027027 | 2016-09 | 2016-Q3 | 2016 |
| 9/26/2016  | 31610061 | 2016-09 | 2016-Q3 | 2016 |
| 9/27/2016  | 31730128 | 2016-09 | 2016-Q3 | 2016 |
| 10/26/2016 | 31585115 | 2016-10 | 2016-Q4 | 2016 |
| 10/27/2016 | 31222400 | 2016-10 | 2016-Q4 | 2016 |
| 10/28/2016 | 31148585 | 2016-10 | 2016-Q4 | 2016 |
| 11/1/2016  | 31216799 | 2016-11 | 2016-Q4 | 2016 |
| 11/2/2016  | 31112343 | 2016-11 | 2016-Q4 | 2016 |
| 11/3/2016  | 30572465 | 2016-11 | 2016-Q4 | 2016 |
+------------+----------+---------+---------+------+
```

I have taken out a lot of the data for simplicity's sake but a row is added for each business day for that day's data. I want to add two columns to this table so that we have a running tally of the quarterly and yearly average NAV. The average is the NAV from the first date of each month as it appears on the table. For example, the 2015-Q1 Average NAV would be the average NAV for 2/2/2015 and 3/2/2015 (instead of the average of each day's NAV from those months) while the 2015 Average NAV would be the average NAV for 2/2/2015, 3/2/2015, 4/7/2015 and 5/7/2015.  I want the end result to look like this:

```
+------------+----------+---------+---------+------+-------------+-------------+
|    Date    |   NAV    |  YrMn   |  YrQt   |  Yr  | QtAvgBegNAV | YrAvgBegNAV |
+------------+----------+---------+---------+------+-------------+-------------+
| 2/2/2015   | 20201975 | 2015-02 | 2015-Q1 | 2015 |    22899939 |    25396136 |
| 2/5/2015   | 20238246 | 2015-02 | 2015-Q1 | 2015 |    22899939 |    25396136 |
| 2/6/2015   | 20220397 | 2015-02 | 2015-Q1 | 2015 |    22899939 |    25396136 |
| 3/2/2015   | 25597902 | 2015-03 | 2015-Q1 | 2015 |    22899939 |    25396136 |
| 3/3/2015   | 25218728 | 2015-03 | 2015-Q1 | 2015 |    22899939 |    25396136 |
| 3/5/2015   | 25332618 | 2015-03 | 2015-Q1 | 2015 |    22899939 |    25396136 |
| 4/7/2015   | 25418590 | 2015-04 | 2015-Q2 | 2015 |    27892333 |    25396136 |
| 4/8/2015   | 25641822 | 2015-04 | 2015-Q2 | 2015 |    27892333 |    25396136 |
| 4/9/2015   | 25554811 | 2015-04 | 2015-Q2 | 2015 |    27892333 |    25396136 |
| 5/7/2015   | 30366075 | 2015-05 | 2015-Q2 | 2015 |    27892333 |    25396136 |
| 5/11/2015  | 30682382 | 2015-05 | 2015-Q2 | 2015 |    27892333 |    25396136 |
| 5/12/2015  | 30302426 | 2015-05 | 2015-Q2 | 2015 |    27892333 |    25396136 |
| 8/23/2016  | 33089750 | 2016-08 | 2016-Q3 | 2016 |    32558389 |    31979673 |
| 8/24/2016  | 32927879 | 2016-08 | 2016-Q3 | 2016 |    32558389 |    31979673 |
| 8/29/2016  | 32788338 | 2016-08 | 2016-Q3 | 2016 |    32558389 |    31979673 |
| 9/23/2016  | 32027027 | 2016-09 | 2016-Q3 | 2016 |    32558389 |    31979673 |
| 9/26/2016  | 31610061 | 2016-09 | 2016-Q3 | 2016 |    32558389 |    31979673 |
| 9/27/2016  | 31730128 | 2016-09 | 2016-Q3 | 2016 |    32558389 |    31979673 |
| 10/26/2016 | 31585115 | 2016-10 | 2016-Q4 | 2016 |    31400957 |    31979673 |
| 10/27/2016 | 31222400 | 2016-10 | 2016-Q4 | 2016 |    31400957 |    31979673 |
| 10/28/2016 | 31148585 | 2016-10 | 2016-Q4 | 2016 |    31400957 |    31979673 |
| 11/1/2016  | 31216799 | 2016-11 | 2016-Q4 | 2016 |    31400957 |    31979673 |
| 11/2/2016  | 31112343 | 2016-11 | 2016-Q4 | 2016 |    31400957 |    31979673 |
| 11/3/2016  | 30572465 | 2016-11 | 2016-Q4 | 2016 |    31400957 |    31979673 |
+------------+----------+---------+---------+------+-------------+-------------+
```

Is there a way to do this? I can get to the correct numbers but I have no idea how to get them on the table. For example, this gives me the yearly average:

```
WITH A AS
(
    SELECT
        s.Date, s.NAV,s.YrMn, s.YrQt, s.Yr, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YrMn ORDER BY Date) AS Row
    FROM 
        Portfolio.DailyNAV s
)
SELECT
    Yr,
    CASE
       WHEN Yr = 2015 AND A.Row = 1 THEN AVG(NAV)
       WHEN Yr = 2016 AND A.Row = 1 THEN AVG(NAV)
       WHEN Yr = 2017 AND A.Row = 1 THEN AVG(NAV)
       WHEN Yr = 2018 AND A.Row = 1 THEN AVG(NAV)
       ELSE AVG (NAV)
    END AS [YrAvgBegNAV]
FROM A
WHERE ROW = 1
GROUP BY Yr, Row
```

However this is not efficient as I have to update the code every year (or every quarter in the case of the quarterly data).  Also, I am going to need multiple joins and views on all of this data so I think it makes sense to have it all on the table. If possible, I would like to alter my original table by adding the quarterly and yearly average data columns (as computed columns).

Comment: Unclear:   do you want to add the columns and do an one-time update to populate them?   Or do you want to create computed columns?

Comment: I want to create computed columns

Comment: Would that be via a view or hard coded

Comment: It would be hard coded. I'm trying to follow Tab's advice and come up with a UDF

Answer (score 1):

I would do this by creating a user-defined function for each computed column that takes the unique key of the table (looks like the `Date` column based on your sample data) and queries the table getting the calculated value for that row, and use the return value of that function for my computed column.

So the computation for `QtAvgBegNAV` would be something like `= dbo.GetQtAvg([date])`

and the `dbo.GetQtAvg()` function would run a query that returns the Qt Average `NAV` for the date that is passed to it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try doing that.